# Currency formatting - Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In a previous .Net life, the way that I would format a currency (any currency) for the current language would be to do something like this:

```
public string FormatCurrencyValue(string symbol, decimal val) 
{
  var format = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
  //overwrite the currency symbol with the one I want to display
  format.CurrencySymbol = symbol;
  //pass the format to ToString();
  return val.ToString("{0:C2}", format);
}
```

This returns the currency value, without any decimal parts, formatted for the given currency symbol, adjusted for the current culture - e.g. `£50.00` for `en-GB` but `50,00£` for `fr-FR`.

The same code running under Windows Store produces `{50:C}`.

Looking at the (rather terrible) WinRT documentation, we do have the [CurrencyFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206883.aspx) class - but it was only after trying to fire the constructor with `"£"` as the parameter, and getting an `ArgumentException` (WinRT documentation is so special - it has practically no information about exceptions) that I realised it wanted an ISO currency symbol (in fairness the parameter name is `currencyCode`, but even so).

Now - I can get one of those as well, but the `CurrencyFormatter` has another issue that makes it unsuitable for currency formatting - you can only format `double`, `long` and `ulong` types - there's no `decimal` overload - which can make for some interesting value errors in some situations.

So how to format currencies dynamically in WinRT.net?

Comment: So I'm not the only one who thinks something called CurrencyFormatter should accept a decimal as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that you can still use old-style format strings with the `NumberFormatInfo` class - it's just that, inexplicably, it doesn't work when you use `ToString`.  If you use `String.Format` instead, then it works.

So we can rewrite the code in my question to:

```
public string FormatCurrencyValue(string symbol, decimal val) 
{
  var format = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
  //overwrite the currency symbol with the one I want to display
  format.CurrencySymbol = symbol;
  //pass the format to String.Format
  return string.Format(format, "{0:C2}", val);
}
```

Which gives the desired result.